# font awesome and images doesn't work in Laravel Voyager

Tags: laravel, admin, voyager

- Hello everyone,

  i use laravel voyager as back-end.. My Admin doesn't work correctly..

  font awesome, images, etc don't appear in the Admin.

  https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3y3c.png

  when i try to Add a product a get this error:

  https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKiPY.png

Can anyone suggest me that what can I do to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check follow:

**First.**

1. Please clear browser cache.
2. php artisan optimize

If it doesn't work let me know how to import font files.

**Second.**

Please set primary key and auto increment on "id" field of "categories" table.

Comment: Query error:
#1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Comment: Please set "id" to primary key and then set to auto increment.